# The view formApp.views.formRegister didn't return an HttpResponse object

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms, django-views

**Views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from . models import Registerform
# Create your views here.

def formRegister(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.POST.get('firstN') and request.POST.get('lastN') and request.POST.get('Email') and request.POST.get('pass'):
            Registerform = Post()
            Registerform.firstName = request.POST.get('firstN')
            Registerform.lastName = request.POST.get('lastN')
            Registerform.email = request.POST.get('Email')
            Registerform.password = request.POST.get('pass')
            Registerform.save()
            return render(request, 'formApp/formreg.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

[image: Error Screenshot]

As you can see in the above error image, my code is not functioning properly. I have added my models.py and views.py code. Please help me to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Why it doesn't work

Every django view, has to return a valid `HttpResponse` object (as the error message says). That is this part of your code:

```
return render(request, 'formApp/formreg.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

The render function is a shortcut which will return such an object.

The problem though is that, all of this is wrapped inside an `if request.method == 'POST':`, and so if the request is something that is not a `POST`, the function just returns nothing. Hence the error

### How to fix it

As you can see in the screen shot you've provided, the request method is a `GET`, so you need to add some code to deal with the case of a GET request.

Add something like this:

```
if request.method == "GET":
    return render(...)  # put what you want here
```